# Limiting the width of a paragraph element CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like my ".tag" div to only be as wide as the text inside it. But, for some reason the paragraph element spans the whole width of the parent element. How can I stop this from happening? So that the ".tag" divs are only as wide as the text inside them?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/X77e7/

My HTML:

```
<div class="tag">
    <p> Hiking </p>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.tag {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.tag p {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `display:inline-block`

It is stretching now because div is by default block element which occupies the whole space.

```
.tag {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4; display:inline-block
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X77e7/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I added float: left to it as well and that did the same thing!

Comment: float may affect the alignment of the div when you use the same div in multiple places. I would suggest display instead

Answer (score 0):

Both `div` and `p` are `block` elements.
So you should consider setting the `display` at `inline`.

```
.tag {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.tag p {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X77e7/2/

Answer (score 0):

just `float` your `.tag` and your problem is solved

```
.tag {
    float:left;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X77e7/4/)